# Transactionally incrementing duplicate record name

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I'll try my best to articulate this problem.  Given this basic object and table schema:

> ### Document
>
> Name :: string

I have a design spec that goes something like:

**Given** a user,
**When** I create a new `Document`,
*And* the `Document.Name` is not unique,
**Then** append " (n)" to the `Document.Name` by finding the highest duplicate index: n, and increment n by one. n initializes to 2 if no duplicates yet exist.
```

### Examples

New Document
New Document (2)
New Document (3)
...

This should look very familiar - similar to how a file system behaves.  However, I'm having issues with handling the scalability of this transaction.

### Control Flow

> POST Document
>
> > Begin Transaction ReadCommitted
> >
> > > GetSimilarDocumentNames (ie "{Document.Name}%")
> > >
> > > ProcessNameForDuplication
> > >
> > > Insert Document
> >
> > Commit Transaction
>
> Return Document

Unfortunately, under parallel requests this will not work and it's apparent we need some kind of locking mechanism.

- Using C# locking won't work across multiple web heads.
- Changing to ReadUncommitted won't help because Request 1 must complete Insert before Request 2 queries for similar document names.

It seems like we need to push this business logic deeper into SQL combined with the use of table locks.  Are there other possible solutions that would not require such restrictive measures?

1. If after-insert triggers are used, I'm assuming they aren't queued up but run instantly and therefore still some kind of locking must occur?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting duplicate numbers because 2 processes fetch the number at the same time calling "ProcessNameForDuplication" before neither of them calls "Insert Document", having a table / functionality like this should help

```
declare @DocNo int

begin tran

update
  Document
set
  @DocNo = DocNo,
  DocNo = DocNo + 1
where
  Name = @DocName

if (@@rowcount = 0) begin
  insert into Document values (@DocName, 2)
  set @DocNo = 1
end

commit
```

To prevent 2 processes from adding the same document, either handling for duplicate row error cases should help, or changing the isolation level to SERIALIZABLE (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) which should lock the table until the documents been added.